# Why don't I get XP in some matches in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Sometimes when a match ends I get no XP at all.

Why does that happen? And how can I make sure that the match I'm in will get me XP? I'm playing on a PC if that matters.

Comment: did you finish the match halfway? or did you leave halfway through

Comment: what do you mean by "no XP at all"? Do you have any evidence/proof of that happening?

Comment: @David No, I played it all

Comment: @Novarg At the end of the match there was no "report" of the XP going up, also no ribbons or anything, just the score. Also, the match doesn't even show up on battlelog, this happened to several matches that I played yesterday

Comment: maybe it was an unranked match?

Comment: @SSumner Tha tis the thing, my filter is always set for ranked servers, can a ranked host have unranked matches?

Comment: @FábioDiniz - I don't believe so. I think that is a server-level setting, not match-level.

Comment: @SSumner Well, I'm clueless then. On these matches I also didn't have any of my unlocks. Maybe some EA servers were down?

Comment: @FábioDiniz - I recall some early bugs where I didn't have any unlocks. But it only happened to me once or twice, and that was within 6 months of release. ([This issue](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71520/i-keep-having-to-unlock-the-same-things-over-and-over-again-for-battlefield-3?rq=1))

Answer (score 1):

When you join the server, try to make sure the server is a "Ranked Match". You can add this to the filter when you're browsing servers. I believe when you click quick match it will always put you in a ranked match.

If you enter a server that's not ranked, you won't receive any XP for match.